# How to display an inline ProgressBar spinner?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to display a ProgressBar spinner in place of another View, while it is loading (i.e. NOT in a dialog). To be clear, I only want the ProgressBar to replace one View, not take over the Window or Activity.

The best solution I can think of is to place both a ProgressBar and the actual View in the layout, with the ProgressBar visibility set to VISIBLE and the View visibility set to GONE. After loading, I swap their visibility.

This will work but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best solution I can think of is to place both a ProgressBar and
>   the actual View in the layout, with the ProgressBar visibility set to
>   VISIBLE and the View visibility set to GONE. After loading, I swap
>   their visibility.

This is a perfectly legitimate solution. If you don't like it, you can try the following:

Add an empty container layout(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.) where you would place the `ProgressBar`, or the `View` that follows. Find this container inside the dialog's view:

```
container = (_____Layout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.container_id);
```

Create `ProgressBar` and the `View` that follows after `loading` ends:

```
ProgressBar pb = ....;

View v = ....;
```

In you code, when `loading` commences:

```
container.addView(pb);
```

Once `loading` finishes:

```
container.removeAllViews();
container.addView(v);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using an AdapterView, you can call the [setEmptyView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) method. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html#Example) for an example.